# HtmlUnit NullPointerException

Tags: java, authentication, null, htmlunit

I'm making a small app to acess to  website

```
public class Main_01 {

private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Main_01.class);

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BasicConfigurator.configure();
    Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.DEBUG);

    Main_01 main = new Main_01();

    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER)) {

        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
        webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(false);

      final HtmlPage pageHome = webClient.getPage("https://www.phpbb.com");
       final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.phpbb.com/community/ucp.php?mode=login");
       System.out.println(page.getTitleText());
        final HtmlForm form = page.getFirstByXPath("//form[@action='./ucp.php?mode=login']");
        System.out.println(form.asText());


    }
}
```

}

gtFirstByXPath returns an NullPointerException but I'm sure 'form action' exists as you can see

is htmlUnit syntax corret ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it throws exception. But this must be work: `//*[@id='wrapcentre']/form`

Comment: I didn't downvote . let me try to get username/password field from div wrapcentre

Comment: fantastic and I learned about Xpath. I 've searched here http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ but where I can found more info about  xpath syntax ?Anyway thx

Comment: @JohnW You are welcome, you can copy anythings XPath in your browser easily. You can try cases.

Answer (score 1):

The form locks like this

```
<form action="./ucp.php?mode=login&amp;sid=966c26f6333def472ee4061a8cabfa96" method="post" id="login" data-focus="username">
```

The attribute value is larger than your search string.

Try something like this

```
page.getFirstByXPath("//form[starts-with(@action, './ucp.php?mode=login')]");
```